# Automatic License Plate Recognition with PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I want to know if i can capture the **text** from a number plate using PHP. If it isnt possible, is there any examples that i can use to implement it and merge it with a PHP application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's you're looking for is called OCR (optical character recognition).

You can try [this](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php) to see if it fits your needs.

If willing to pay, you also have [this](http://ocrsdk.com/) option.

Comment: thanks alot for your reply. I have tried the first (free option) but it seems complicating to implement. Can you assist me in doing so?

Comment: It is complicated indeed, the same as you project. It requires effort and time that I don't have; good luck! :)

Comment: You're welcome, good luck! If you have problems while implementing what I gave you, you can ask here.